# How to destroy objects to minimum value in Range attribute? some objects still exist when the range value is 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

mono script:

```
using BezierSolution;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.TerrainTools;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class RandomBezierSpline : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Bezier Spline")]
    [Range(2f, 100f)]
    public int numberOfBeziers = 2;
    public bool randomNumberOfBeziers = false;
    public BezierSpline bezierSpline;
 
    private int oldNumberOfBeziers;
 
    public void GenerateBezier()
    {
        if (oldNumberOfBeziers != numberOfBeziers)
        {
            bezierSpline.Initialize(numberOfBeziers);
 
            oldNumberOfBeziers = numberOfBeziers;
        }
    }
}
```

editor script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.TerrainTools;
using UnityEngine;
 
[CustomEditor(typeof(RandomBezierSpline))]
public class RandomBezierSplineEditor :Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
 
        RandomBezierSpline randomBezierSpline = (RandomBezierSpline)target;
 
        randomBezierSpline.GenerateBezier();
    }
}
```

the part of another script that creating the objects:

```
public void Initialize( int endPointsCount )
        {
            if (endPointsCount <= 2)
            {
                return;
            }
 
            // Destroy current end points
            endPoints.Clear();
            GetComponentsInChildren( endPoints );
 
            for( int i = endPoints.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
                DestroyImmediate( endPoints[i].gameObject );
 
            // Create new end points
            endPoints.Clear();
 
            for( int i = 0; i < endPointsCount; i++ )
                InsertNewPointAt( i );
 
            Refresh();
        }
```

The problem is when i move the Range slider in the inspector to the right increasing the value it's creating new Point's objects. but then when i slide the Range slider to the left decreasing the value it's destroying the Point's but when the slider is at value 0 there are still Point's left sometimes 2 sometimes 4 sometimes more or less but it's never destroyed all the Point's objects when getting to the value 0.

Update :

i tested it again and it seems like when I'm sliding the Range slider too fast to the left side it can't handle it and can't destroy all the Point's objects. the fastest I'm moving the Range slider the more Point's left. if i move the slider very slow the best i can get is left with 3 Point's but it should be 2 the minimum of Point's is 2.

is there a way to work around this slider moving speed problem?

here is a screenshot after i moved the Range slider to the right and the value is 17 there are 17 created Point objects :

[image: slider at value 17]

now depending on the speed i drag and move the slider to the left side how much point object will be left in the hierarchy :

in this case i moved the slider very fast and the slider value is 2 but in the hierarchy there are 14 point objects.  because i moved the slider so fast it couldn't handle and destroy all the point objects so the vlaue is 2 but there are 14 objects :

[image: moved/dragged the range slider very fast to the left]

and this screenshot is when i moved the slider very very slow to the left i moved it one by one and the value is 2 but there are 3 point objects left :

[image: moved the slider very slow to the left]

what i want to do is when i move the slider to the right create Point object depending on the value it is currently.  but if i keep moving it to the right add the amount of needed objects for example i moved to the right and stopped at value 7 then i moved it again from 7 to 14 then it should create more 7 objects to the already existing 7 and not create 14 new ones.

same if i'm moving it to the left to remove objects same logic and to solve also the speed problem.

Comment: `if (endPointsCount <= 2) { return; }` .. I would probably start here

Comment: Why do you have a custom `RandomBezierSplineEditor` at all? Looks liek you just could do your thing within `RandomBezierSpline.OnValidate` which is called fo evey change made via the Inspector -> exactly what you are dealing with ...

Answer (score 1):

If you call add/remove points when the slider value changes, you should get the difference between old slider value and the new one. This is the number of points you want to add/delete.

Moving slider too fast can skip some values.

I assume you don't want to loose the Points already in the scene, so generating them every time from scratch is not an option.